# Does postgresql have Database-level triggers?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to build a trigger in postgresql that will fire when the server starts.

In Oracle I can use

```
CREATE TRIGGER iii AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE
```

Comment: @MitchWheat Not fair for a SQL question. Personally I can't stand seeing SQL keywords in lowercase.  Spent half the day today working on a legacy 500 line SQL Server procedure that was _entirely_ lowercase. I was itching all over.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: Check the original question: I wasn't referring to the TSQL....

Comment: @MitchWheat Ah indeed, sorry! :)

Comment: FYI, there's work in progress to implement "event triggers" which are likely to be extended to this sort of thing. Search the pgsql-hackers mailing list for more info. At this point, there's no such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  [Postgres triggers can only fire when a query is run against a table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

As a kludge, you might be able to find a table that's modified in certain way at database startup (perhaps there's an INSERT to some system table?) but depending on this would be a hack.